# How can I call the 'upper class' this keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script that contains a function that uses a callback to return status, and I have to commit whether or not it was successful to a class variable. I can't use `this` to get access to it, since it's not in the scope. I can't post code snippets of my exact code, but the following should illustrate my issue

```
var thisObject = Item.prototype;
function Item(directory){
     this._completedTasks = [];
     this._fsDirectory = directory;
     if (!fs.existsSync(this._fsDirectory)){
         fs.mkdirSync(this._fsDirectory);
     }
}

thisObject.doStuff = function(url){
     goGetFile(url, function(message){
         this._completedTasks.push(url);
         //_completedTasks appears to be undefined here.
     });
}

module.exports = Item;
```

How can I access the variable `_completedTasks`?

Comment: try `var _self = this; goGetFile(...){ _self._completedTasks.push(url);})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things, save a reference to `this` and then use that, or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the execution context

```
//Saving a reference
thisObject.doStuff = function(url){
     var that = this;
     goGetFile(url, function(message){
         that._completedTasks.push(url);
     });
}

//Using bind
thisObject.doStuff = function(url){
     goGetFile(url, function(message){
         this._completedTasks.push(url);
     }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Works great. Would not have thought of this one myself. I was originally going to go in and completely redefine the function so I could pass in the array reference and have it return it to the callback, but this works so much more elegantly.